# Google Express - Orderinvoices: createchargeinvoice

Tags: magento2, google-apis-explorer, google-shopping-api

I am integrating Google Express with Magento but the Create charge invoices API is failing for me. I tried to create the invoice from the "Try this API" option of Google merchant but it's throwing the following error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "content.ContentErrorDomain",
    "reason": "invalid_transition",
    "message": "The requested order is not supported by orderinvoices service"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The requested order is not supported by orderinvoices service"
 }
}
```

createchargeinvoice API doc: https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/reference/v2/orderinvoices/createchargeinvoice

My request body:

```
{
  "invoiceId": "invoice1",
  "operationId": "charge1",
  "shipmentGroupId": "shipmentgroup1",
  "lineItemInvoices": [
    {
      "productId": "online:en:US:d3k3245",
      "shipmentUnitIds": [
        "2"
      ],
      "unitInvoice": {
        "unitPricePretax": {
          "value": "140",
          "currency": "USD"
        },
        "unitPriceTaxes": [
          {
            "taxType": "sales",
            "taxAmount": {
              "value": "14",
              "currency": "USD"
            }
          }
        ],
        "promotions": [
          {
            "promotionId": "111",
            "promotionAmount": {
              "tax": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "value": "0"
              },
              "pretax": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "value": "0"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "additionalCharges": [
          {
            "additionalChargeAmount": {
              "pretax": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "value": "0"
              },
              "tax": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "value": "0"
              }
            },
            "additionalChargePromotions": [
              {
                "promotionAmount": {
                  "pretax": {
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "value": "0"
                  },
                  "tax": {
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "value": "0"
                  }
                },
                "promotionId": "111"
              }
            ],
            "type": "shipping"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "invoiceSummary": {
    "productTotal": {
      "pretax": {
        "value": "561.20",
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "tax": {
        "value": "55.98",
        "currency": "USD"
      }
    },
    "additionalChargeSummaries": [
      {
        "totalAmount": {
          "pretax": {
            "value": "561.20",
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "tax": {
            "value": "55.98",
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        },
        "type": "shipping"
      }
    ],
    "promotionSummaries": [
      {
        "promotionAmount": {
          "pretax": {
            "value": "561.20",
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "tax": {
            "value": "55.98",
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        },
        "promotionId": "111"
      }
    ],
    "merchantBalance": {
      "pretax": {
        "value": "561.20",
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "tax": {
        "value": "55.98",
        "currency": "USD"
      }
    },
    "customerBalance": {
      "pretax": {
        "value": "561.20",
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "tax": {
        "value": "55.98",
        "currency": "USD"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: The error is pointing to the malformed request body. Please share the request body as well.

Comment: @KamranFeroz: I have updated my question with the request body.

Answer (score 0):

As per the google document (that you've shared), there are around 40 "Required" fields for the request body. In the current shared request body, you've less than half of the required fields.

### Required fields:

1. invoiceId
2. operationId
3. shipmentGroupId
4. lineItemInvoices[]
5. lineItemInvoices[].shipmentUnitIds[]
6. lineItemInvoices[].unitInvoice
7. lineItemInvoices[].unitInvoice.unitPricePretax
8. lineItemInvoices[].unitInvoice.unitPriceTaxes[].taxType
9. lineItemInvoices[].unitInvoice.unitPriceTaxes[].taxAmount
10. lineItemInvoices[].unitInvoice.promotions[].promotionId
11. lineItemInvoices[].unitInvoice.promotions[].promotionAmount
12. lineItemInvoices[].unitInvoice.promotions[].promotionAmount.pretax
13. lineItemInvoices[].unitInvoice.promotions[].promotionAmount.tax
14. lineItemInvoices[].unitInvoice.additionalCharges[].type
15. lineItemInvoices[].unitInvoice.additionalCharges[].additionalChargeAmount
16. lineItemInvoices[].unitInvoice.additionalCharges[].additionalChargeAmount.pretax
17. lineItemInvoices[].unitInvoice.additionalCharges[].additionalChargeAmount.tax
18. lineItemInvoices[].unitInvoice.additionalCharges[].additionalChargePromotions[].promotionId
19. lineItemInvoices[].unitInvoice.additionalCharges[].additionalChargePromotions[].promotionAmount
20. lineItemInvoices[].unitInvoice.additionalCharges[].additionalChargePromotions[].promotionAmount.pretax
21. lineItemInvoices[].unitInvoice.additionalCharges[].additionalChargePromotions[].promotionAmount.tax
22. invoiceSummary
23. invoiceSummary.productTotal
24. invoiceSummary.productTotal.pretax
25. invoiceSummary.productTotal.tax
26. invoiceSummary.additionalChargeSummaries[].type
27. invoiceSummary.additionalChargeSummaries[].totalAmount
28. invoiceSummary.additionalChargeSummaries[].totalAmount.pretax
29. invoiceSummary.additionalChargeSummaries[].totalAmount.tax
30. invoiceSummary.promotionSummaries[].promotionId
31. invoiceSummary.promotionSummaries[].promotionAmount
32. invoiceSummary.promotionSummaries[].promotionAmount.pretax
33. invoiceSummary.promotionSummaries[].promotionAmount.tax
34. invoiceSummary.merchantBalance.pretax
35. invoiceSummary.merchantBalance.tax
36. invoiceSummary.customerBalance.pretax
37. invoiceSummary.customerBalance.tax
38. invoiceSummary.googleBalance.pretax
39. invoiceSummary.googleBalance.tax

Comment: I have updated the request body with all the required fields, but still getting the same error. Is it something to do with the GE order status? My order is in "Shipped" status now.